# Сортировка в общем списке кусками. Как исправить?

Tags: битрикс

Умный фильтр по умолчанию работает только в разделах. Его конечно можно настроить и на общий список, независимо от раздела. Я настроил. Однако теперь общий список сортируется по разделам: то есть сначала сортировка по цене в разделе А, затем в разделе Б и т.д. Получается что у меня общий список с выполненной сортировкой, но этот список состоит из кусков, отсортированных внутри себя.

Есть ли такое свойство для компонента умного фильтра (или каталога), которое позволит сортировать весь общий список, а не список кусками?

Answer (score 0):

Грамотные программисты читают документацию. ;)

Во-первых вы должны понять, что есть компонент bitrix:smart.filter (умный фильтр) и есть компонент bitrix:catalog.section (элементы раздела). Первый ни коем образом не влияет на сортировку.  Его задача отобразить свойства и их значения актуальные для текущего урл, а так же на основании текущего урл подготовить фильтр. Следовательно для этого компонента ни какого свойства влияющего на сортировку нет и быть не может. Он не выводит элементы сортировать не его задача.

Список элементов выводит соответствующий компонент (bitrix:catalog.section) и именно у него есть параметр отвечающий за сортировку. Этот компонент просто использует фильтр подготовленный компонентом умного фильтра.

И из коробки все нормально сортирует. По-этому прежде чем кидаться на битрикс постарайтесь разобраться, что у вас там сделано и как. Увы этот геморрой скорее не от битрикс, а от разработчиков не читающих документацию.

Предполагать что у вас там случилось сложно. Первое на ум приходит, что у вас сортировка у компонента выводящего товары именно так и настроена: разделы, потом цена.

Еще теоретически может быть:
 - у вас в каждом разделе свой тип цены
 - У вас товары с торговыми предложениями - в этом случае бывают накладки при сортировке по цене (в прочем решаемые, если понимать, что и как работает)

Итак для начала каким компонентом вы выводите "общий список" и какие у него настройки сортировки?